# In Excel VBA customize all userforms from a single procedure

Tags: excel, vba

I have userforms grouped by similiar properties, which user can change. rather than doing this change in each userform's initialization sub, I want to do this in a sub to shorten the code.

I am getting a 438 error

The called sub and the caller are below. I am getting a run time error 438 and could not resolve it.

```
Public Sub customizeCurrentUserForm(ByRef userFormName_Send As Object)
            With userFormName_Send
                .Width = ThisWorkbook.canvasWidth
                ...
                ...
            End With
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    customizeCurrentUserForm (Me)
End Sub
```

Comment: Workbook doesn't have a `canvasWidth` member.  You also need to remove the parens around `(Me)` - that's forcing it to be passed `ByVal`. Finally, `customizeCurrentUserForm` has to be in a standard module - it can't be in a document or class module.

Comment: I just removed the paranthesis between ME and it worked. Thanks for the advice. -----------  canvasWidth is a variable I have defined in my main module (Thiswortkbook) and I am using its full name to identify it clearly. It is not meant to be a proterty or method of the workbook. customizeCurrentUserForm is a asub in module2. there is no problem with activating the right module but width can not be assigned.

Comment: "canvasWidth is a variable I have defined in my main module (Thiswortkbook)" -- *how* is it declared then? Use `Dim` for local variables, `Private` for private module-scope variables, and `Public` for public ones. Side note, `ByRef userFormName_Send As Object` would probably be better off as `ByVal form As UserForm` -- "userFormName" looks like it's a *name* (string), and the underscore-send "_send" makes it look like an event handler; avoid underscores in class names and public members, they will cause compile errors at one point or another. And there is no need to pass it `ByRef`.

Comment: İt was defined "Public". Problem was solved by removing () around Me. Now works fine.